# Bootstrap small text class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating an input button with `btn-link` to make the button styled like a text link.

I want to make the text smaller so tried

```
<button class="btn btn-link">
  <small>Hello World</small>
</button>
```

This however does not not perform the same as

```
<input type="button">
```

So I wondered if there is a Bootstrap class for text that is the same size as the `<small>` tag? I couldn't find anything. Or can someone suggest an alternative method? (ideally I don't want to be creating my own class, I just want to use what's available in Bootstrap.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you asked, I have tried to simulate. Try to run. Thnx

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">Button</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link ">Button</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-lg">Button</button>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: btn-sm is what I was after. Alas it's not small enough for me, so will have to go custom. Cheers

Comment: try <em> also inside <a> tag